# Why URI constructor allows missing protocol (while URL does not)?

Tags: java, url, uri

Why does URI allow missing protocol (while URL does not)?

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition) Scheme (and even Path) seem to be obligatory components of an URI:

> The URI generic syntax consists of a hierarchical sequence of five
>   components:[8]
>
> URI = **scheme**:[//authority]**path**[?query][#fragment]

Or missing protocol defaults to something (like http)? I found nothing like this in the docs.

```
new URI("my.html");        // 1
new URI("xabc:my.html");   // 2
new URL("my.html");        // 3      
new URL("xabc:my.html");   // 4
```

Concerning "obligatory" path - OK, there is oblique URI. But why missing protocol is allowed (it shall be present even for obligue URI which is required to be absolute)

I could understand that *relative* URL/URI don't require protocol (`<img src="/images/pic.png">`), but URL gives run-time `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol` in this case either (while URI don't).

Comment: Show code that throw `MalformedURLException` exception

Answer (score 1):

Your relative path must be wrong, 
Java's [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) supports empty scheme for relative URI:

> relative URI, that is, a URI that does not specify a scheme. Some examples of hierarchical URIs are:
>
> ```
> docs/guide/collections/designfaq.html#28
> ```

Scheme is optional:

> ```
> [scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]
> ```

Similar with [URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-url), e.g.:

> ```
> URL url = new URL("/guidelines.txt");
> ```